# Have unique combination of multiple attributes

Tags: mysql, sql, database

What I am trying to do is set up the database table so that a set of multiple attributes must be unique but can be put in the database as many times as possible. For example if I had the following information with ID as the primary key:

```
 id    email                  name     value
  1      a@gmail.com           A        AValue
  2      a@gmail.com           A        BValue
  3      b@gmail.com           B        CValue
```

I don't want to have

```
 id     email                 name     value 
  4      a@gmail.com           B        yetAnotherValue
```

combination possible where the email is to a different name. I want it to throw an exception. Is there any way to do this without a trigger or creating a separate table. If not , why not? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question implies that `name` should be "dependent" on `email`.  As such, your schema violates [3NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) and, absent good reason, should be avoided: instead, you should have a table of `(email, name)` pairs with a `UNIQUE` constraint defined over the `email` column (and another over the `name` column, if the same name cannot be associated with multiple email addresses):

```
CREATE TABLE email_names (PRIMARY KEY (email))
  AS SELECT DISTINCT email, name FROM your_table
```

Then your data table should simply contain a foreign key into this new table:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table
  DROP COLUMN name,
  ADD FOREIGN KEY (email) REFERENCES email_names (email)
```

To retrieve the names with your data, you would need to join the tables together in the relevant `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT o.id, o.email, n.name, o.value
FROM   your_table AS o JOIN email_names AS n USING (email)
```

---

However, there *are* sometimes good reasons for using denormalised schema—often when performance concerns are at play—and constraints of this nature *can* be enforced in MySQL.  Before citing "anticipated" performance concerns, one should be mindful of Knuth's maxim that "*premature optimisation is the root of all evil*", and that the above approach will be very performant due to the indexing employed.  Nevertheless, to enforce this constraint in your existing table:

1. Create a composite index over the combined columns in the table created above:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE email_names
     ADD INDEX (email, name)
   ```
2. Then, **instead** of the above changes to your current table, define a *composite foreign key* into the new table:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE your_table
     ADD FOREIGN KEY (email, name) REFERENCES email_names (email, name)
   ```

Comment: I would agree with this approach.  In this case the email/name pair is a stand alone object which need to the value stored in this table.

Comment: This would also allow "a@gmail A" along with "a@gmail B" ... Composite key is not the way to go. the email/names table requires 2 DISTINCT unique constraints... (He wants that One name is 1:1 related to One Email Adress)

Comment: @dognose: Good spot.  Corrected.

Comment: @eggyal: You also need to add another unique key for name. If some User (a@gmail) picks the name "dognose", no other user should be able to pick the name "dognose", even if he has different email. :)

Comment: @dognose: I'm not certain whether the OP intended for that to be the case, but I already edited my answer to cover that situation.

Comment: On second thought... you may be right (assuming name/value to be a key/value pair, EACH user requires to have access to EACH name, while NO double names should be possible for ONE email...) edit: hmm, but this would be violated by the example, also...

Comment: Thank you all. For some reason I didn't think to look to deeply into the normalized form. It seems this is in 2NF and I will correct it to 3NF with your recommendations